# Android Launching Camera Intent from Fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-fragments

I currently have an activity that hosts multiple fragments and I am on my third fragment of a collection.

In that fragment I use an Intent to launch either the Camera or Gallery. See code:

```
public Intent getImageIntent() {

    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    // Filesystem.
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");

    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
            cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[] {}));

    // Calling activity should exeecute:
    // startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, 1);
    return chooserIntent;
}
```

After that the onActivityResult executes:

```
private void handleSmallCameraPhoto(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    mProductBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    imgProduct.setImageBitmap(mProductBitmap);
}
```

Where mProductBitmap is a Bitmap Global Variable and imgProduct is an ImageView already initialized.

**For some reason, first: The Camera option force closes the app, and gets a null pointer from the actual fragment itself, like the fragment items are all null again.
Second: The gallery options (More then one) don't error out but don't show the image either.**

Any help would be appreciated. I've looked at every response possible, but not many people call an intent from a fragment that isn't the initial fragment that the activity is hosting.
Thanks!

EDIT:
Found out sometimes my Context is Null after the onActivityResult. If anyone has encountered this help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Below is by onActivityResult method, most of the time the first if should be executed.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        handleSmallCameraPhoto(intent);
    } else {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            InputStream stream = null;
            if (intent == null) {
                System.out.println("DATA IS NULL..");
            } else {
                try {
                    if (mProductBitmap != null) {
                        mProductBitmap.recycle();
                    }
                    stream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                            intent.getData());
                    mProductBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                    System.out.println(mProductBitmap);
                    System.out.println("Setting image result");
                    imgProduct.setImageBitmap(mProductBitmap);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (stream != null)
                        try {
                            stream.close();
                        } catch (IOException e2) {
                            e2.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: where you are initializing context in Fragment?

Comment: Can you show the code where you do `startActivityForResult(...)` ?

Comment: @GopalRao The context in a fragment is taken from its activity, so in this instance I use a CameraImage object and initialize the context when constructing it.

Comment: @yurezcv I edited my initial question with the method. Hope that helps, but not much more needed.

Comment: Did you solve that problem? I am having same issue

Comment: No luck as of yet @GokhanArik. (I haven't looked at it for a couple of weeks though) I also forgot to mention I'm using a library to Scan UPC's that takes hold of the Camera initially but then releases it in the same activity that the fragment above is hosted in.

Comment: The app forces to close or the Activity is being killed?

Comment: Neither, from a user's standpoint nothing is wrong (app doesn't die etc), but after debugging I've found the Context to be null within the method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your photo is saved in `PATH_TO_SAVE` location.

You should in `onActivityResult` do something like this:

```
File file = new File(PATH_TO_SAVE);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
```

Comment: I've currently abandoned this feature for now, and will circle back to it later. I'll accept this answer because it seems what I am missing. Thanks.